# Why do these two codes print something different?

Tags: python

Why does this code:

```py
for x in range(len(grid[0])):
    print(grid[x])
```

return this:

```
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.']
['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.']
```

and this code:

```py
for x in range(len(grid)):
    print(grid[x])
```

return this:

```
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.']
['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.']
['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
```

the list grid:

```py
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
        ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.']
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.']
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.']
        ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.']
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.']
        ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.']
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

Comment: because `len(grid)` and `len(grid[0])` are different

Comment: You may want to mention which package `grid` comes from.

Comment: Thanks, @DeveshKumarSingh! Problem solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`len(grid)` gives you the number of elements in the list `grid` (9, because there are 9 sublists).

`len(grid[0])` gives you the number of elements (in this case, strings) in the first element (sublist), and there are 6.